# How to connect from Xubuntu 16.04 to remote Windows 10 with audio in/out

Tags: sound, xubuntu, rdp

I wanted to connect to my Windows 10 (pro) at the office, mainly in order to be able to use Skype for Business. For this you need audio in both directions. Have a broadband connection that makes RDP work nicely. This how to explains how I did it with my setup:

Local:

- Xubuntu 16.04 (expect it to work similar on Ubuntu)
- Logitech webcam C525 + Speakers
- xfreerdp (2.0.0-dev (git n/a))

Remote:

- Windows 10 Pro v1607

Inbetween:

- VPN

Answer (score 1):

Windows preparations:

- Enable RDP on Win10 (search for guides)
- Enable re-direction of microphone for remote audio

For the latter step: Type "`run`" in windows search and run "`gpedit.msc`". Find "`Allow audio recording redirection`" and enable it. (This is a crucial step, otherwise you won't get your microphone working remotly).

On Xubuntu:

- Install a recent build of xfreerdp (I'm using a nightly build installed as described in https://ci.freerdp.com/job/freerdp-nightly-binaries/ )
- Start it from /opt/freerdp-nightly/bin/ like this

`$ ./xfreerdp /d:<domain> /u:<user> /size:1920x1135 /sec:rdp /sound:sys:pulse /microphone:sys:alsa /clipboard +fonts /v:<ip address to Win10 box>`

That is it! I've added a launcher to the panel and with one click I have access to the remote desktop with audio in and out (after starting VPN of course). Very nice work flow, better then using Windows in VMs etc.

My main problem was with the microphone when trying to use a /microphone:sys:pulse setting, the sound was all garbled, but with the alsa setting it works very good. I would think that the outcome may depend on the HW, especially microphone, you're using so please add your experiences.

Answer (score 0):

WOOHOO, the GPEDIT bit was the magic piece! For anyone who comes after, in Local Group Policy editor, Computer Configuration > Administrative templates > Windows components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Device and Resource Redirection.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I find this answer difficult to follow. I think you're explaining where to find a relevant setting but I'm not sure. Can you please edit to clarify your suggestion, and how it relates to the other answer you referred to?